# Best method to store JWT Token for multi-domain usage

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I want to allow users to access wp-rest-api on my Wp-instance on my-domain.com from multiple friend wordpress blogs on friend1-domain.com, friend2-domain.com etc. using jwt-authentication (aam-plugin).

All friend-domains have plugin-for-friends installed.
This plugin-for-friends sends a POST-request to a specific aam-plugin generated endpoint: my-domain.com/wp-json/aam/v2/authenticate with user credentials. The respond returns the user-specific JWT for authentication to friend1-domain.com for example.
The user can do all the magic things, what plugin-for-friends allows from friend1-domain.com.

I want to store authentication JWT in users browser securely, so that user can jump to another blog friend2-domain.com doing there more magic staff using plugin-for-friends, without need for new authentication (using JWT from browser storage).

How do do that? If you could illustrate your answer with some code, would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You ll have to set the JWT cookie on your domain with samesite=None.
What happens is when you are firing a request from  friend1-domain.com or friend2-domain.com , the jwt set from your domain is not shared with those requests as per latest browser versions now(initially by default samesite was being set none, which was later changed to "Lax" for security reasons).
When samesite is set to None it means that third party domains can send this cookie while firing requests for your domain which can be authorized by your domain.
you can read more on this samesite cookie and how to use it here https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

You ll also have to set secure=True while setting samesite=None.